# Convert XML to Json and remove XML declaration from converted Json

Tags: xml, json, json.net

I have the following XML file that I need to convert to JSON. I am able to convert it to Json using Newtonsoft library but it includes xml declaration part also.How can i skip xml declaration part and convert remaining file to json?

I am using below code(C#) to convert it.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(employeeXMLDoc)
```

Sample xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Employee>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <EmployeeName>XYZ</EmployeeName>
</Employee>
```

Json Output

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8"},"Employee":{"EmployeeID":"1","EmployeeName":"XYZ"}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove the first child from the `XmlDocument`:

```
employeeXMLDoc.RemoveChild(employeeXMLDoc.FirstChild);
```

And then serialize as you're doing now.

Answer (score 2):

Or in a single line:

`JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(employeeXMLDoc.FirstChild.NextSibling);`